# Select rows from mysql table with limit by group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, limit

I have the table

```
id    code    name
=====================
1     30100   John
2     30100   Andrew
3     30100   Sandy
4     29145   Mike
5     29145   Tony
6     29145   Laura
7     29145   Henry
8     00124   Michael
9     00124   Teddy
10    13405   Andy
11    09325   Patrick
```

I want to select only 2 names grouped by code and get this result.

```
id    code    name
=====================
1     30100   John
2     30100   Andrew
4     29145   Mike
5     29145   Tony
8     00124   Michael
9     00124   Teddy
10    13405   Andy
11    09325   Patrick
```

Can somebody help me to make such query/queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, code, name
FROM   TableName a
WHERE
(
   SELECT count(*) 
   FROM   TableName as f
   WHERE  f.code = a.code and a.id >= f.id
) <= 2
ORDER BY id, code, name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e56e1/4)

Comment: And is it possible to make a sql query to get different quantities of each code (ex: 30100 - 2, 29145 - 3, 09325 - 4 [but returns only one])?

Comment: what do you mean by returns only one?